# Need help returning the response from an API?

Tags: node.js, request, response

I want to return the response from the below API. What is wrong with this snippet. it receives the expected result but it doesn't return the response (it returns nothing).

```
export const findWeatherStats = async () => {
    try {
        let weatherStats: any;
        await request("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=6.9270786&lon=79.861243&appid={appid}&units=metric",
            {json: true}, (err, res, body) => {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
                weatherStats = body;
                console.log(weatherStats);
            });
        return weatherStats;

    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I’m not wrong request is deprecated. You can use native fetch API or axios library.

Fetch - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
Axios - https://axios-http.com/docs/intro

Answer (score 0):

You should try `weatherStats = res.body`.